# Ink 'n Paint Material does not work with ThreeJS?

Tags: three.js, paint

I want to render all the vertexes and the lines in the mesh.

I tried

1) A custom shader following this link

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2028

2) Set transparency with the material or like:

```
THREE.MeshNormalMaterial( { transparent: true, opacity: 0.5 } ),
```

3) Set ink material to the model in 3dMax and export to an obj file and load it in Threejs with `objloader`

None of them works fine.

Is there any solution to load mashes from 3dMax model (using objloader) and apply it with ink material in Threejs, just like what we can do in 3DMax?

See below as an example
http://makeitcg.com/wireframe-rendering-techniques-in-3ds-max/160/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Number 3) will NEVER work with OBJ, because obj will not export the ink shader from 3dsMax. And just to be clear, i don't think there is ANY way you can export the 3dsMax Shader. 
Then, I don't understand what 2) is about. What do you want to achieve anyway? Do you want to set an object to be transparent? What does this have to do with Ink 'n Paint? Btw. i am not sure if transparency works for MeshNormalMaterial, i guess it should but Lambert and Phong will definetly work with transparency.

The problem is that you do not state what you want to achieve. From 1) it seems you want an outline around an object. For an outline see this example: http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Outline.html or this one as a more advanced example: http://stemkoski.blogspot.de/2013/07/shaders-in-threejs-glow-and-halo.html

If you want to set transparent objects, well try MeshLambert or meshBasic material if MeshNormal does not work (i am not sure Right Now and can't check)

3) if you want to have a Ink 'n Paint shader, you need a Custom Shader. See examples here:

http://www.chromeexperiments.com/detail/cel-shader/
and already done with three.js here: 
http://learningthreejs.com/data/THREEx/docs/THREEx.CelShader.html
Just apply the shader, see examples for setting up a ShaderMaterial.

Comment: Thank you GuyGood! I would like to render all the vertexes and the lines in the mesh ( or in some way control how to render them), even they are not on the edge or outline, similar as you seen it in 3dmax editor- an object made of grid lines.

Comment: well, then see also those maybe: 
http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Topology-Data.html
http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Topology-Data-2.html
http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Polyhedra.html
and all of stemkoski's examples!!! :) they are all great :)
edit: p.s. please accept the answer if it helped you^^

Comment: Awsome, you are the king!
I can see I need to do some coding. It will be nice if Threejs can provide an inline function :)
BTW, the 2nd link seems not working with my browser.

Comment: true, does not work, but check his wehole example page anyway ;)  Have a nice day ^_^